# How to get Thorn?

Tags: destiny

Is there a way to obtain the Thorn in year two of Destiny? I don't know of any way to get it.

I'm looking for it because Thorn is my favorite hand cannon EVER.

Comment: There is no Y2 version. If you owned it previously I believe you can purchase it from a weapons kiosk using Legendary Marks. And, perhaps, you can get it from the Legacy Engrams that Xur sells.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starters - there is no year 2 version of Thorn.

With the removal of exotic bounties, there are no ways to specifically target Thorn. However, you can run year 1 content (raids like Vault of Glass or Crota's End, or the Prison of Elders) all of which have a chance to reward Year 1 exotics. Finally, Xur sometimes sells legacy exotic engrams for 36 strange coins. These will always decrypt to a year 1 exotic, with a strong bias (but not a guarantee) towards ones not already in your collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Thorn from nightfalls, raid drops, three of coins or if you have year 1 version you can just buy it from the kiosk

Comment: Year 2 content doesn't reward you with Year 1 gear, so I don't think you could receive Thorn from nightfalls or three of coins. To my knowledge, it can drop from either Vault of Glass or Crota's End, but I am not 100% on that.

Comment: there is a year 2 thorn though, that's what they want to get

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I can find zero evidence to validate the existence of a year 2 Thorn. It's definitely not available in my Kiosk despite owning a year 1 Thorn.

Answer (score 1):

Now that Year 3 and Rise of Iron have come around, it's time for an updated answer. There is a new version of Thorn, and the quest for it is given in the same way as in Year 1 - there's a small chance to get the quest upon turning in any bounty.